# Django contact e-mail form does not render/show up in template home.html

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views, django-forms

**Django project structure**

Parent directory: personal_portfolio_project
Main sub-direcory (containing the settings): personal_portfolio
Apps: portfolio, blog

Directory structure of the entire project with all its apps (printed out in the console via [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)):

```
├── personal_portfolio_project
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20210117_1306.py
│   │   │   ├── 0003_auto_20210117_1309.py
│   │   │   ├── 0004_auto_20210117_1432.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0002_auto_20210117_1306.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0003_auto_20210117_1309.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │       ├── 0004_auto_20210117_1432.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── blog
│   │   │       ├── all_blogs.html
│   │   │       └── detail.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── portfolio
│   │       └── images
│   │           ├── DSC_0004a.jpg
│   │           └── DSC_0010a.jpg
│   ├── personal_portfolio
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── portfolio
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __pycache__
│   │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │       └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── portfolio
│   │   │       ├── CV_Andreas_Luckert.pdf
│   │   │       ├── DSC_0010a.jpg
│   │   │       ├── Logo_Andreas_Luckert.png
│   │   │       ├── Logo_ZappyCode_DjangoCourse.png
│   │   │       ├── custom.css
│   │   │       └── main.js
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── portfolio
│   │   │       ├── about.html
│   │   │       ├── base.html
│   │   │       └── home.html
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── test_sendgrid.py
```

---

**Story - line**

I have a `portfolio/forms.py` - file in the "portfolio" - app with the following content:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    from_email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
    # From docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#more-on-fields
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

In the `portfolio/views.py` I have the following relevant part:

```
from .forms import ContactForm  # import module from same parent folder as this script
import General.Misc.general_tools as tools  # custom module to import special-print function

def contactView(request, admin_email='blaa@blaaa.com'):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        sendemail_form = ContactForm()
    else:
        sendemail_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if sendemail_form.is_valid():
            # * Retrieve data and set up e-mail (subject, sender, message)
            subject = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['message']
            # From docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#more-on-fields
            cc_myself = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

            recipients = [admin_email]
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(from_email)

            # * Send email
            try:
                # General Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail
                # NOTE on passed list as 4th parameter: recipient-list

                ## i) How to set up an email contact form - docs: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-email-contact-form
                send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          from_email,
                          recipients,
                          fail_silently=False)

            # * Exceptions * #
            # NOTE on scope: security
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            # General exception to be printed out
            except Exception as e:
                tools.except_print(f"ERROR:\n{e}")

            # Return success (if this code is reached)
            return redirect('success')

    # Send the completed (filled-in) form to the homepage - HTML - document
    return render(request, "portfolio/home.html",
                  {'sendemail_form': sendemail_form})


def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

This is the contact form I included at the very end of my `portfolio/templates/portfolio/home.html` (the rest of the `HTML` works perfectly fine and generally `Django` does not show any errors in the console while displaying the `localhost`-webpage):

```
<!-- ** E-Mail contact form **
Docs: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-email-contact-form-->

{% if sendemail_form %}
    <h2 class="mt-5">Contact Me</h2>
    <hr>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- NOTE on ".as_p": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options
        Possible attributes: as_table, as_p, as_ul -->
        {{ sendemail_form.as_p }}
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

The content of my `personal_portfolio/urls.py` is the following:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings  # get info from the settings.py - file
from portfolio import views  # other views could also be imported (e.g. from the blog-app)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),

    # Docs: https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-email-contact-form
    path("contact/", views.contactView, name='contact'),
    path("success/", views.successView, name='success'),

    # Add "About me" for additonal info about the creator of the webpage
    path("about/", views.about, name="about"),

    # Standard admin page
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # NOTE on include: forwarding all /blog/ - related requests to the blog-app
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]

# * Add a static link to the MEDIA - files * #
# NOTE on processing: import certain variables defined in the settings.py of this project
# Docs: google django images (or media (folder)) etc.
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I tried to register the form in the `portfolio/admin.py` just like classes defined in `portfolio/models.py`, but first of all I don't know if that's necessary and secondly it didn't even work due to the `TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable`, so I removed the following code from the `portfolio/admin.py` afterwards:

```
from django.contrib import admin
# !!! CAUTON: TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable
from .forms import ContactForm

# NOTE on registering form: doesn't work due to the following error:
# TypeError: 'DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass' object is not iterable
admin.site.register(ContactForm)
```

By and large, I'm confused as to how to make the form finally appear on my `portfolio/templates/portfolio/home.html`.
As the `{% if sendemail_form %}` scans for a `non-None` form to be passed, this indicates that the form is not passed correctly as it should.

---

**Test** to check whether the function `contactView()` in `views.py` calling the contact-form is reached with a printout in it:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 19, 2021 - 14:16:37
Django version 3.1.5, using settings 'personal_portfolio.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[19/Jan/2021 14:16:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 31617
[19/Jan/2021 14:16:42] "GET /static/portfolio/custom.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[19/Jan/2021 14:16:42] "GET /static/portfolio/main.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[19/Jan/2021 14:16:43] "GET /static/portfolio/Logo_ZappyCode_DjangoCourse.png HTTP/1.1" 200 442438
```

--> According to the console it is not reached, since the printout does not appear.

Comment: Did you pass your contact form in your `home` view ?

Comment: I'm new to django and not entirely sure what you mean, @Benbb96, but hopefully the directory tree will help understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the `ContactForm` in the home view that renders the home page. We need to do this because the form appears in the home page template; if we don't add the form in this view, then the contact form part of the template never will work because it receives `None`.

```
def home(request):
    ... your code here ...

    # send empty contact form to template
    sendemail_form = ContactForm()

    return render(
        request,
        "portfolio/home.html",
        {'sendemail_form': sendemail_form})
```

Then the `contactView` should never render a template, just redirect. The job of the `contactView` is to get the POST data and process it, and the redirect to a differnt view; it should never render a template.

```
def contactView(request, admin_email='blaa@blaaa.com'):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sendemail_form = ContactForm(request.POST)

        if sendemail_form.is_valid():
            subject = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['message']
            cc_myself = sendemail_form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

            recipients = [admin_email]
            if cc_myself:
                recipients.append(from_email)

            try:
                send_mail(subject,
                          message,
                          from_email,
                          recipients,
                          fail_silently=False)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            except Exception as e:
                tools.except_print(f"ERROR:\n{e}")
                return HttpResponse('errors.')

            # Return success (if this code is reached)
            return redirect('success')

    # return to home page
    return redirect('home')
```

---

Also, point your contact form (which is located in the home page template) to the correct URL (which is the contact URL, not the home URL); you could change:

```html
{% if sendemail_form %}
    ...
    <form method="post">
    ...
{% endif %}
```

to

```html
{% if sendemail_form %}
    ...
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Now it finally works, thanks a lot! For some reason the process of the webpage https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-email-contact-form was proposing it the way I had it initially. The resulting contact-form looks very basic regarding the style, but that's another topic I'm going to try resolving it via google :P

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the correct URL to the contact HTML form.

You say that the HTML form is located in the home page, but the HTML form does not specify a different `action` (the target URL), so it will post (send a HTTP POST request) to the home page URL, which uses the view `views.home`, and that is not what you need.

By specifying a different HTML action attribute in the form, the page will send the data to a different URL (should be `contact`), which should then use your view `views.contactView`.

Try changing your HTML code for the contact form (in the home page template) from

```html
{% if sendemail_form %}
    ...
    <form method="post">
    ...
{% endif %}
```

to

```html
{% if sendemail_form %}
    ...
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'contact' %}">
    ...
{% endif %}
```

---

Also, add the `ContactForm()` in the view of your home page as well.

Comment: It makes sense, thanks for the explanation. I've just implemented it, but the form still doesn't show up.

Comment: @AndreasL. Are you sure that your `contactView` is being used? You could try by placing print statements inside the view to see which parts of the view are reached.

Comment: Actually, I've already tried that, but I will repeat the intent. I'm sure it is not used, otherwise it'd return the form. Maybe the directory tree of the entire django project (see note at the end of my post) will help solve the problem.

Comment: @AndreasL. you need to add `sendemail_form = ContactForm()` to your home view as well. Do you have that? Or could you add your home view code to the question?

Comment: This is part of the `portfolio/views.py` I posted above: `if request.method == 'GET':
        sendemail_form = ContactForm()
    else:
        sendemail_form = ContactForm(request.POST)`. But apparently, this function never gets reached, I've inserted a printout which was not sent to the console. As for the directory structure, I did it according to a udemy.com - course, so I'm confused as to what is actually my "home"-directory. Is the home directory that one where the `settings.py` are located? Then, this would be `personal_portfolio`, but there is no `views.py` because this is no app.

Comment: I've just added the relative paths of `views.py, forms.py, home.html` etc. in the beginning of the initial post along with the entire directory structure of the project. I'm very sure that the problem lies in how the contact-form is called, since it can't look it up properly.

Comment: @AndreasL. I suspect you might be creating the contactform in the wrong view. I added another answer because it is a lot of code I need to show.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with your new answer it works!